# Client Side Cannot Find Client Cert in TLS Mutual Authentication

Tags: windows, ssl, tls, client-certificate

This is a windows .NET application. Am working on the client side. Increased SSChannel logging and discovered ... .

```
Creating a TLS client credential.

The remote server has requested TLS client authentication, but no suitable client certificate could be found. An anonymous connection will be attempted.
This TLS connection request may succeed or fail, depending on the server's policy settings.

A fatal alert was received from the remote endpoint. The TLS protocol defined fatal alert code is 40.
```

The cert is in the Cert Store, but it's loaded in the application. Also, the Extended Key Usage appears correct.

- Client Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2)
- Secure Email (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.4)

No clue why the client side cannot find the cert and not sure what else to check for. The cert if from DigiCert and the intermediate and root certs are in place as well.

Edit: Adding the server packet capture showing that server is requesting the client cert.
[Server Package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGj9A.png)

Comment: When the (TLS) server requests client authentication (aka mutual authentication or client certificate) in the CertRequest message it can and usually (but not always) does specify which CAs it wants; does the server you are connecting to specify (at least one of) the DigiCert CAs you are using? If you have OpenSSL (e.g. in a WSL distro or 'git-bash') or get it from http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html `openssl s_client` will attempt a connection and show you this info under a heading `Acceptable client certificate CA names`.

Comment: Yes the server does request the client cert, and the CN name matches that is in the cert store. We did a wireshark capture packet to see what the packets back and forth. I'll paste the packet in question.

Comment: The name shown in your capture is the name of a server (aka end-entity) not of the/any CA. That name could be (and I expect is) the Subject of your cert but not the Issuer, and only a chain with a cert whose _Issuer_ matches the request will be selected. See the bottom of https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#page-56 : the/a cert should be issued **by** a requested CA, not issued **to** a requested CA. PS: 'CN' != 'CA'. 'CN' is a standard abbreviation for CommonName which is _part_ of (_one_ attribute in) a 'DN' = Distinguished Name (via an 'RDN' = Relative Distinguished Name).

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085 for weighing in. I am out of my depth here I am afraid. Yes, the name in my packet capture is the certificate subject name. The issuer is DigiCert. Both the intermediate and root DigiCert certs are on the server. I can load the cert (windows) and I can view the intermediate and root certs. I'm not sure if you're feeding me the answer to the issue and I am not getting it, or just instructing me on how this is supposed to work. Either way, I apprecitate you assistance and instruction.

Comment: I am understanding a bit more now. I see the Certificate packet form the client just after the Server Hello packet, and there are three Certificates listed. I assume these are the client, intermediate and root certs. After that packet, I get to the Server Key Exchange packet and I see there that it lists several client certs, not all of which we have but one of with is the one we sent them in the Certificate packet. Then I see the Certificate Client Key Exchange with NO certificate. So, for some reason, the client cannot find the cert that I know it has?

Comment: There cannot be a Certificate message from client before ServerKeyExchange; that's the _server_ Certificate message _to_ the client. ServerKeyExchange does not contain any certs of any kind, _or_ CA names; the CertificateRequest message, which is different, contains CA names but not certs. _After_ CertificateRequest and ServerHelloDone, the client sends _two_ messages, one Certificate then one ClientKeyExchange. If _that_ Certificate message contains an empty sequence i.e. no actual certificates, then client doesn't have a certificate matching the server's request. ...

Comment: ... To repeat more verbosely what I said, your server is asking for a chain containing a cert whose _CA_ name -- that is, the Issuer field -- is `WEX DXC Client Cert`. The cert you have has that name as Subject, not Issuer, and the Subject name in an EE cert is an EE name and is NOT a CA name. Because you don't have any cert whose _Issuer field_ matches the server's requested CA name, your client can't and doesn't do client-aka-mutual authentication.

Comment: Sorry, yes. The Certificate packet was from the server to client. As I understand it, in the ServerKeyExchange, the server is asking for the certificate to use in authentication. In this case, its WEX DXC Client Cert. That cert is in the cert store and its Issuer is DigiCert.

Comment: No, ServerKeyExchange does not request client cert/auth, as I already said CertificateRequest does. And when it requests `WEX DXC Client Cert` that means client should use a cert with `WEX DXC Client Cert` as the Issuer (CA) -- NOT as the Subject. Your cert does not have `WEX DXC Client Cert` as the Issuer so it does not match the server's request and is not used and no mutual-auth occurs. I don't know any words more simple and basic than that I can use to explain this.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to be obtuse. I get what you are saying. Thanks for the assistance.